# How can I dynamically fetch and parse JSON data in Jinja2 templates using JavaScript?

Tags: python, json, ajax, flask, jinja2

I am working on a web application where I need to fetch JSON data from a server and dynamically update the content of an element in my Jinja2 template every 5 seconds without reloading the whole page. I am using JavaScript for the client-side functionality and Jinja2 for rendering the template.

Here's an overview of what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Fetch JSON data from the server at regular intervals (e.g., every 5 seconds).
2. Parse the received JSON data.
3. Update a specific element in my Jinja2 template with the parsed data.
4. Repeat the process to ensure the content remains up-to-date without page reloads.

Here is the current code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        /* CSS styles for the dark theme */
        body {
            background-color: #1c1e21;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .post-container {
            background-color: #323739;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .post-content {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .post-author {
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .post-date {
            color: #8b8d92;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .new-post-container {
            background-color: #323739;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .new-post-input {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            resize: none;
        }

        .new-post-button {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Function to fetch and update posts
        function updatePosts() {
          // Use AJAX to fetch the updated posts data
          fetch('/api/posts')  // Replace '/api/posts' with the actual URL to fetch your posts data
            .then(response => response.json())  // Assuming the response is in JSON format
            .then(data => {
              // Update the posts section with the new data
              const postsContainer = document.getElementById('posts-container');
              postsContainer.innerHTML = '';  // Clear the existing posts
      
              // Loop through the new data and create HTML elements for each post
              data.posts.forEach(post => {
                const postElement = document.createElement('div');
                postElement.className = 'post-container';
                postElement.innerHTML = `
                  <div class="post-author">${post.author}</div>
                  <div class="post-content">${post.content}</div>
                  <div class="post-date">${post.date}</div>
                `;
      
                postsContainer.appendChild(postElement);  // Add the post element to the container
              });
      
              // Schedule the next update after 2 seconds
              setTimeout(updatePosts, 2000);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              // Handle any errors that occur during the AJAX request
              console.error('Error fetching posts:', error);
              // Schedule the next update after 2 seconds, even if an error occurred
              setTimeout(updatePosts, 2000);
            });
        }
      
        // Start the initial update
        updatePosts();
      </script>      
</head>
<body>
    <form class="new-post-container" action="/api/post" method="post">
        <input class="new-post-input" type="text" name="content" placeholder="The post content">
        <input class="new-post-input" type="text" name="author" placeholder="Your name">
        <button class="new-post-button" type="submit">Post</button>
    </form>

    <div id="posts-container">
        {% for post in posts %}
            <div class="post-container">
                <div class="post-author">{{ post["author"] }}</div>
                <div class="post-content">{{ post["content"] }}</div>
                <div class="post-date">{{ post["date"] }}</div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my flask server if it helps:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from datetime import datetime
from utils import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index(): return render_template('index.html', posts = load_posts())

@app.route('/api/post', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        create_new_post(request.form['content'], datetime.now().strftime("%B %d, %Y"), request.form['author'])
        return "Success", 201
    else: return load_posts()
    
app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

I would appreciate any guidance on how to implement this functionality using JavaScript and Jinja2. Specifically, I'm looking for suggestions on handling the JSON fetch and parsing, as well as dynamically updating the element in my Jinja2 template with the parsed data.

Comment: Stack overflow questions that do not contain code are not *automatically* off-topic, but they almost always are off-topic. Until you have a good feel for what makes a good stack overflow question I would suggest that you not post any questions that do not contain code along with sample input and a description of the desired vs. observed output. This isn't a single question, it's 4-5 questions. Pick one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have edited the question to include my code.

Comment: That's a big step in the right direction. What about your current code is not working? Please be extremely specific like "I call function foo with x and expect to have y returned but am observing z".

Comment: how would you do it without Jinja2 templates, so it the same in the template, the template just creates the start HTML code

Comment: convert the result of `load_posts()` to a JSON file with a JinJa2 template that contains a for loop, and set the correct result MIME type of JSON, then look in the browser if you get  a JSON file by opening a tab to `/api/post`

Comment: why does `index.html` also render posts, when the first thing the page does is fetch the posts, just return a post-empty `index.html` and let the fetch do the post rendering, saves you the need to update the post rendering twice

Comment: you could dramatically simplify this by using HTMX https://htmx.org/docs/#polling

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan how do I do this in HTMX? please answer in a answer